# GET minimum value from two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
student

id | marks 
1  |  5 
2  |  4
```

and

```
point

id| points
3 |   3
4 |   5
```

both tables are different columns in the tables are different what I want is a Sql query which can check the minimum value from `student. Marks` and `point. Points` and give me a single output

i.e. desired output is 3 which is minimum value  from both tables

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a union. Something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(val) FROM
(SELECT marks AS val FROM student
UNION
SELECT points AS val FROM point) AS data
```

If you want to know the id of the min row you could order by val:

```
SELECT top 1 id, VAL FROM
(SELECT id, marks AS val FROM student
UNION
SELECT id, points AS val FROM point) AS data 
ORDER BY VAL
```

If you want to see all rows with min value we can all rows where the value is the min value
(please note that for this we need UNION **ALL**)

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id, marks AS val FROM student
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, points AS val FROM point) AS data 
WHERE val = 
   (SELECT MIN(val) FROM
   (SELECT marks AS val FROM student
   UNION
   SELECT points AS val FROM point) AS data)
```

If you wish to show which table the min came from you can add a column for that:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id, marks AS val, 'Student' as source FROM student
UNION ALL
SELECT id, points AS val, 'Points' as source FROM point) AS data 
WHERE val = (
        SELECT MIN(val) FROM
        (SELECT marks AS val FROM student
        UNION
        SELECT points AS val FROM point) AS data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select min(val)
from ((select min(marks) as val from students) union all
      (select min(points) from points)
     ) sp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can try this way
`select MIN(MIN(marks), MIN(point)) from student,point;`
```